# how to get specified info from a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have this schema

```
const todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
details: String
})
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    todo: [todoSchema]
})
```

i want a rout that gets a specified todo (based on name) for a specified user
this code

```
await User.findOne({ 'todo._id': req.body.todo_id, _id: req.body.id })
```

its get all the information of the user not a Single ToDo
such as if i got this

```
 "user": {
    "todo": [
        {
            "_id": "60fc3bd454b38c19a0afd09a",
            "name": "hi",
            "details": "hello"
        } , {
            "_id": "60fc3bd454b38c19a0afd09b",
            "name": "bye",
            "details": "goodbye"
        }
    ]
}
```

how can i get the `todo[1]` details
how should i fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) is what you want.

```
await User.findOne(
{ 'todo._id': req.body.todo_id,
 _id: req.body.id },{
'todo.$': 1 }
})
```